# Proper way to manage Daemons, Debian/Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, daemon

What is the best way? Or at least... an easily managed one?

I am routinely creating shell and python scripts that need to always be running in the background.

Any recommendations on packages that simplify this?  In the past I would stick a shell script in cron to check for the running process, but this feels like a hack.  I recently read about a program called Angel, which is written in Haskell that does this, but this seems like a common use that would be built in to the OS somewhere.

edit: What tool would reduce the time I spend on this activity and result in something both easily maintainable and quickly deployable to new servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I regularly use [supervisor](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/supervisor) for this kind of tasks. Especially for scripts that do not justify the creation of a complete SysV-init script.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for!  "Especially for scripts that do not justify the creation of a complete SysV-init script."

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses a custom version of */sbin/init* called [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

---

On Debian, I think you use [SystemV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style) scripts, though I'm not sure.

SystemV, if that is the case, is managed via a program called `service`.

They are [chaning things](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2009/09/msg00003.html), though. This idea was planned for Lenny (released a year ago), but I don't know if it is actually implemented.

Comment: I consider this a general linux administration question.  I deploy across several flavors of linux and will not be picking a particular tool as a solution unless it is cross-linuxy.

Comment: @mvrak: Then to [superuser](http://superuser.com/) it is!